# Relative path / Absolute path queries doesn't work from current directory

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, relative-path, absolute-path

While traversing from my current path , and searching for a file , I'm having problems locating the file .

I suspect the that the `path` is the blame for that due to `chdir` , in the next code  :

The associated folders are :

- 12,13,14 , 12 is father directory
- 13 inside 12 , 14 inside 13
- david1.txt inside 14
- **get_current_dir_name()** is a Linux function , not mine

I run the executable file from `Desktop` , like this (here are `printf-s` for trying to locating the problem) :

```
    // doesn't work 

   a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12 david1.txt

    Current path is :12

    Current path is :/home/a/Desktop/12/13

    Current path is :/home/a/Desktop/12/13/14

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // doesn't work      

    a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12/13 david1.txt

    Current path is :12/13

    Current path is :/home/a/Desktop/12/13/14

////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // doesn't work 

    a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12/13/14 david1.txt

    Current path is :12/13/14
```

If I remove these lines :

```
chdir(path);                          // the problem is probably here 
strcpy(path, get_current_dir_name()); // and here
```

Then every query that involves only a single library name - works , for example :

```
// works : 

a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12 david1.txt

Current path is :12

Current path is :12/13

File found!

12/13/14/david1.txt-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 2012-06-17 08:10 

Current path is :12/13/14
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// works 
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12/13 david1.txt

Current path is :12/13

File found!

12/13/14/david1.txt-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 0 2012-06-17 08:10 

Current path is :12/13/14

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Doesn't work
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 12/13/14 david1.txt

Current path is :12/13/14
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ? I've tried to change countless times but nothing fixed it . Thanks

Comment: if you think there is a problem, why didn't you check the return code.

Comment: Show the rest of the code, otherwise it's hard to tell.

Comment: How do you check if the file is existed in the directory?Show us some code to locate the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `strcpy(path, get_current_dir_name())`, you don't check that the buffer isn't exceeded.
If `path` is `argv[1]`, you're overrunning the stack.
My guess is that you overrun the file name (`argv[2]`), and then you start looking for the wrong name (and don't find it).

Answer (score 2):

Add some my debugging information to help you know the reason clearly.

Before running `strcpy(path, get_current_dir_name());`

```
 Breakpoint 1, traverseDirectories (path=0xbfbfeda8 "src", recursive=1, filename=0xbfbfedac "2.db") at main.c:30
    30               chdir(path);

0xbfbfeda8:     0x73    0x72    0x63    0x00    0x32    0x2e    0x64    0x62
0xbfbfedb0:     0x00    0x54    0x45    0x52    0x4d    0x3d    0x78    0x74
0xbfbfedb8:     0x65    0x72    0x6d    0x00    0x53    0x48    0x45    0x4c
0xbfbfedc0:     0x4c    0x3d    0x2f    0x75    0x73    0x72    0x2f    0x6c
```

After running `strcpy(path, get_current_dir_name());`

```
0xbfbfeda8:     0x2f    0x75    0x73    0x72    0x2f    0x68    0x6f    0x6d
0xbfbfedb0:     0x65    0x2f    0x6e    0x65    0x6f    0x2f    0x73    0x72
0xbfbfedb8:     0x63    0x00    0x6d    0x00    0x53    0x48    0x45    0x4c
0xbfbfedc0:     0x4c    0x3d    0x2f    0x75    0x73    0x72    0x2f    0x6c
```

See the difference?It is why your function not works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
if (S_ISDIR(fstat.st_mode))
```

you first check the fstat.st_mode whether it is directory, then find the your target file. If you use function `chdir()`, when the directory chang into 12/13/14, it will not make the condition false, `displayAllFiles(full_name , filename)` will
not be called.

Comment: So if I'll move the call for `dhdir()` into `main` and only then call the recursion , you it would do ? I'll try that now

Comment: @ron, I have write a similar function to find what causing the problem, and I find why.Just as ugoren says, you have a stackoverruning, the first time you run traverseDirectories, the argv[1]'s size is determined, its size is the length of argv[1], and then you run strcpy(), it overrunning the content of argv[2]

Comment: I did something else now , from main : `  char path[4096];
  char filename[4096];
  strcpy(path,argv[1]);         // copy the folder to search
  strcpy(filename,argv[2]);   // copy the file to search`

Comment: I want to see him overflowing/running to me now :)

Comment: @ron, it is easy, because you using strcpy, to avoid unexpected situation, you'd better to use strncpy.And you'd better to give a tick to ugoren, he help you find the problem first.